# how to get ANY user info facebook api not developer or tester

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

i can get User albums photos, comments etc. with facebook api but
just admin, developer or tester's datas.

how can i get just user's datas?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get the full functionality in your app only after Facebook App Review. For this you have to submit your app for review and once Facebook approves it only will be available to normal users.

In the development phase all the permissions will be available to those who are added as developers or testers in the Facebook admin panel.

For information regarding facebook app submission visit the link below

[HOW TO SUBMIT YOUR APP FOR FACEBOOK REVIEW?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit)

Hope this helps....